# User input upperCase and lowerCase - Java

Tags: java

I am attempting to take an input of A or B in either Uppercase or LowerCase to follow on through the if statement. I can't figure out how to do this. At the moment, it's only taking in UpperCase A or B. Looked around the forum and the class notes, came up with nothing. Any help would be appriciated!
I tried using toUpperCase() but don't think i am putting it in the right place. It keeps giving me an error

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class printNumber{
    public static void main (String[] args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please select an option between A or B: ");
        char user = input.next().charAt(0);

        System.out.println("You have selected " +user+ " : ");    
        if (user == 'A'){
            for(int n=1; n<=100; n++){
                if((n%2)==0)
                    System.out.println(n);
            }
        }
        else if (user =='B'){
            for (int x =1; x<=100; x=x+2){
                System.out.println(x);
            }
        }
        else
            System.out.println("Error, please try again!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
char user = input.next().toUpperCase().charAt(0);
```

Comment: You are welcome and consider marking one of the answer as accepted to mark your question as solved

Answer (score 3):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class printNumber{
  public static void main (String[] args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please select an option between A or B: ");
    String opt=input.nextLine();

    System.out.println("You have selected " +user+ " : ");

    if (opt.equalsIgnoreCase("A")){

    for(int n=1; n<=100; n++){
      if((n%2)==0)
        System.out.println(n);
     }
    }
    else if (opt.equalsIgnoreCase("B")){
    for (int x =1; x<=100; x=x+2){
      System.out.println(x);
     }
    }
    else
      System.out.println("Error, please try again!");
  }
}
```

or you can simply use

```
  import java.util.Scanner;

    public class printNumber{
      public static void main (String[] args){
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.println("Please select an option between A or B: ");
        String opt=input.next();

        System.out.println("You have selected " +user+ " : ");

        if (opt == "A" || opt == "a"){

        for(int n=1; n<=100; n++){
          if((n%2)==0)
            System.out.println(n);
         }
        }
        else if (opt == "B" || opt == "b"){
        for (int x =1; x<=100; x=x+2){
          System.out.println(x);
         }
        }
        else
          System.out.println("Error, please try again!");
      }
    }
```

Comment: hey andrew, quick question. What's the purpose of the readLine in this case? Is it because opt is a String in this case rather than char?

Comment: I've changed my answer. We use readLine() method to read InputStream.Example:
 InputStreamReader in=new InputStreamReader(System.in);

    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(in);

    String a=br.readLine();

Comment: @Andrew Watson you should not use **==** operator to check two Strings, it will only compare address locations (**opt** and String literal will be in two different locations), use **equals()** method which in String class is overrided to compare data of two objects, in the second portion of your code.

Comment: We can use == it for string literal definately. It wont conflict but if we make string object and then use of == , won't give true rather false as object location is not same in the heap.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
if (user == 'A' || user == 'a')
```

The same for 'B'

Comment: Ah, I see. I was doing this 
(user == 'A'||'a').

Answer (score 2):

You are calling `next()` method of `Scanner` class, which returns `String`, so rather than converting it into a `character` you can use `equalsIgnoreCase()` method on the input String for validation. But always check the length of the input string and show error message if the length of the string entered by user is greater than 1.

`"a".equalsIgnoreCase("A")` and `"a".equalsIgnoreCase("a")` will be always true.

Comment: I appreciate your concept but you should keep the input in a variable and then compare it with equalsIgnoreCase

Comment: @Andrew Watson, what I meant by input is the data entered by user and not the Scanner reference. Thanks for noticing, I've edited my question.